# Why is my Clockify API request for a Detailed Report only filtered by a specific client ID only returning the entries for 1 user?

Tags: clockify

I'm using the Clockify API with my user API key to get all time entries for a specific client.

However I'm only getting the time entries for one of the users of the team and not all the users of the team.

I've tried to filter specifically on other users of the team but I get 0 time entries.

I can see on the web browser UI multiple time entries for all users when filtering on the same client so it shouldn't be a problem of permissions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add the API query you are using so we can see what you are doing to assist you further.